# Ubuntu 17.04 taking too much time to boot

Tags: boot, performance

My laptop has a core i3 processor, 4 GB RAM and a 1 TB SATA HDD.
It takes too much time to boot.

```
     31.658s nmbd.service
     22.035s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     14.369s preload.service
     14.245s click-system-hooks.service
     12.016s ModemManager.service
     11.097s dev-sda1.device
     10.114s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.552s irqbalance.service
      5.533s networking.service
      5.329s accounts-daemon.service
      5.204s NetworkManager.service
      5.179s sddm.service
      5.173s speech-dispatcher.service
      5.171s loadcpufreq.service
      4.710s winbind.service
      4.657s lm-sensors.service
      4.626s appgrid.service
      4.626s gpu-manager.service
      4.248s avahi-daemon.service
      4.243s thermald.service
      3.858s fwupd.service
      3.802s apparmor.service
      3.648s dnsmasq.service
      3.562s upower.service
      2.473s polkit.service
      2.432s plymouth-read-write.service
      2.320s smbd.service
      2.302s grub-common.service
      2.095s gdm.service
      1.986s keyboard-setup.service
      1.846s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.811s rsyslog.service
      1.521s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BFC4\x2d9612.service
      1.521s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.263s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.242s systemd-resolved.service
      1.188s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.114s systemd-udevd.service
       997ms apport.service
       934ms dns-clean.service
       863ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       862ms dev-hugepages.mount
       860ms dev-mqueue.mount
       842ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       787ms user@126.service
       760ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       758ms openvpn.service
       707ms user@1000.service
       697ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       539ms dev-sda3.swap
       491ms hostapd.service
       455ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       415ms ufw.service
       413ms hddtemp.service
       411ms systemd-sysctl.service
       407ms rc-local.service
       392ms alsa-restore.service
       388ms udisks2.service
       378ms console-setup.service
       371ms switcheroo-control.service
       371ms pppd-dns.service
       365ms systemd-journald.service
       363ms colord.service
       336ms snap-core-1689.mount
       268ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       242ms plymouth-start.service
       242ms systemd-random-seed.service
       235ms packagekit.service
       228ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
       208ms dev-loop0.device
       192ms snap-pin\x2dtown-2.mount
       180ms boot-efi.mount
       180ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       167ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       119ms dev-loop1.device
       106ms setvtrgb.service
        96ms wpa_supplicant.service
        44ms resolvconf.service
        38ms geoclue.service
        37ms rtkit-daemon.service
        32ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        20ms snapd.socket
        18ms snapd.autoimport.service
        12ms cpufrequtils.service
         8ms ureadahead-stop.service
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms lightdm.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: How long, in seconds, is too long?

Comment: almost 3minutes, i guess.... i mean 180 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in recovery mode and choose fix fchk when text menu appears with first option "resume". After fixing file system hit "resume" and restart at login...

Comment: thanks! it dramatically reduced almost 30 seconds of boot time..... but still almost 38 seconds it iss taking to start the graphical "ubuntu splash animation"

Comment: You can make a better disk fix/check up by creating an USB startup disk (downloading Ubuntu ISO), and after booting from USB choose try Ubuntu and hit Windows key and start Gparted app. There choose your disk and check it, it gets callibrated and fixed.